Create new column values depending on other columns' values
I have a huge data set, and after cleaning it, I would like to create new columns with values, depending on the values in other columns. (Cleaning the dataset means removing bunch of useless columns and rows)
For example:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=10, size=7)

Classes = ['M', 'M', 'X', 'M', 'X', 'M' , 'M']
Intensity = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in values ]

data = pd.DataFrame()
data['Class'] = Classes
data['Intensity'] = Intensity
data

This gives a data frame with 2 columns, kind of similar to the actual datafrma, and I want to create new columns 'M5-M10', 'X1-X5', 'X5-X10', and 'X10+', and fill these columns depending on the values of the 'Classes' and 'Intensity' columns. If the class is an "M" and the Intensity is >5, in that row the column 'M5-M10' should get a '1', the other columns a '0', and if the class is 'X' and the intensity >1 but <5, the column 'X1-X5' should get a '1', the other columns a '0', etc. The rows should not be shifted, because in the original dataframe there is also a column with time, which I need to use as an index.
I tried to define a new function and applying it to the dataframe:
def label_flare(df1):
   if df1['Class'] == 'M' and df1['Intensity'] >= '5':
      df1['M5-M10'] == '1'
   else: df1['M5-M10'] == '0'
   if df1['Class'] == 'X' and df1['Intensity'] >= '1' and df1['Intensity'] <= '5':
      df1['X1-X5'] == '1'
   else: df1['X1-X5'] == '0'
   if df1['Class'] == 'X' and df1['Intensity'] >= '5' and df1['Intensity'] <= '10':
      df1['X5-X10'] == '1'
   else: df1['X5-X10'] == '0'
   if df1['Class'] == 'X' and df1['Intensity'] >= '10':
      df1['X10+'] == '1'
   else: df1['X10+'] == '0'

df1.apply(label_flare)

But this does nothing to the dataframe.
Edit: it could be that there are M3.3 or M2.9 flares in the data frame, but I am only interested in the M5-M10 and X-flares, and and M10 is equal to an X1, so there won´t be any M10+ in the data frame.

Use data = data.apply(label_flare, axis=1) and for assign new value use = instead ==

It means df1['M5-M10'] == '1' - compare by '1', df1['M5-M10'] = '1' assigned '1'

@jezrael I've chnged the '=='  to '=' to assign a new value, but I still get an error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'float'
Is this because the 'M' or 'X' is a str?

Error is with data in question?
